# FOSUserBundle Multiple Registration

Tags: symfony, registration, fosuserbundle

I am planning to have 2 different registration forms for same type of user. One registration with minimum User Entity fields however another with more advance form fields.

I have tried with creating different form Type for another form but somehow it's not trigger validation. Everytime it pass the validation even for empty form submitted.

If I look at config.yml settings there is only allowed option/key is "registration", how can I add additional form registered in config.yml (I am hoping that this could be the most specific entry point I belive)

Anyone come across this issue before?

Comment: You should show some code/configuration file of your attempts so that we have a chance to understand what's going wrong.

Comment: Use one Type for both forms and event listener to add additional fields when you need advanced form.